# Codec error when writing Python dictionary into CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Below is a sample of my dictionary:

```
dict = {'Croatia': '191', 'Cuba': '192', 'Curaçao': '531', 
        'Cyprus': '196', 'Czechia': '203',  'Czechoslovakia': '200',
        "Côte d'Ivoire": '384',  "Dem. People's Rep. of Korea": '408',
        'Dem. Rep. of the Congo': '180', 'Denmark': '208'}
```

My goal is to try to write the diction into a csv file so each row will have one key and one value, such as:

> Croatia, 191
>
> Cuba, 192

and I am using `csv` for this purpose:

```
import csv
with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
for key, value in dict.items():
   writer.writerow([key.encode('utf-8'), value])
```

when not using `key.encode('utf-8')`, Python gives the error of **'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf4' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)**, presumably cuased by `Côte d'Ivoire` in the dictionary. However, even when a csv file can be successfully produced now, the csv file itself contains additional characters `b'countryname'` instead of `countryname`.

(see the image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9dJu.jpg)

How do I solve this particular issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) cover how to handle encoding.  Trying to encode individual elements does not, as you have seen, work out well.

Comment: leveraging known python solutions is an excellent answer.  The python 3 version of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend you to use `Pandas` for your purpose.

```
import pandas as pd

country_name = dict.keys()
cnt = dict.values()
df = pd.DataFrame({'countryname':country_name,'count':cnt})
df.to_csv('result.csv',sep=',',encoding='utf-8')
```